# How can I view a summary of all git modifications since a certain commit

Tags: git, history

Essentially I would like a list of all modified files so I can export those particular files to move into an SVN repo used for staging purposes. No need to track changes or history, just the filenames.

So far I have:

```
git log --oneline --summary a0a3e56..
```

Which only gives me a list of deletes and creates, no modifications.

It also doesn't summarize across commits, but that doesn't bother me too much since I'm happy to pipe the output with something along the lines of :

```
git log --oneline --summary a0a3e56..|egrep -v '^ delete'|awk '/^ / {print $4}'|sort|uniq
```

I don't need to know about deletions at all.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git diff --name-status a0a3e56..
```

It will give you entries of the form A, M or D (for added, modified or deleted respectively), tab, filename and newline. Should be trivially parsable by any script tool. Or you can add the `-z` option, in which case you'll get A, M or D, NUL, filename, NUL for exact parsing in presence of newline character in filenames.